# how to scrape file download via click download button - python

Tags: python

I want to automate downloading process from https://tide.pier.or.th/chart/CPIA0. I do see the inspect the web but it does provide any download URL.

I found that the web run a function that return download URL when I click download button and "Excel data" via chrome console. However, the download URL is changed when I reopen the website.

I have no idea to deal with this issue to gather download URL and automate download process. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its fairly simple, Just download selenium webdriver.

https://www.selenium.dev/

And then record and perform your actions, Download it as a **Python script** and run.

Try it out here and comment if you need any help

P.S. don't forget to give a upvote.

Comment: Good to hear, drop an upvote so that others can use this as well.